# Trying to sort a list of lists in a "special" way...I think

Tags: python, sorting

I have a list of lists that looks something like this:

```
test_list = [['V1'],['V3','V2'],['V3'],['V2','V1'],['V1','V2']]
```

And I want it to end up like this:

```
sorted_list = [['V1'],['V1','V2'],['V2','V1'],['V3','V2'],['V3']]
```

(Note the 'V's are an artifact of my use case, but are probably irrelevant because they are a constant prefix.)

The list may have any number of elements, but will always have exactly 2 single-item lists (the "ends", always containing the lowest and highest numbers in the list). The rest are 2-item lists that will go in between. Those need to be sorted by their first element.

It seems I can do this with "brute force", separating the single and double item lists, sorting both, then inserting the doubles back into the singles, like this:

```
sorted_list = sorted([x for x in test_list if len(x) == 1])
doubles_list = sorted([x for x in test_list if len(x) == 2])
sorted_list[1:1] = doubles_list
```

But I keep thinking there's a more elegant or compact way to do this that I just can't see. (And I've also been looking at it so long I can't tell if that's really a robust, bulletproof way to do it.)

Any insight appreciated!

Comment: What is the reason `['V3','V2']` would proceed `['V3']` yet `['V1']` proceeds `['V1','V2']`? That is not consistent.

Comment: There is a geometrical basis here that seemed irrelevant/difficult to explain, sorry. In brief, I have a set of ribbon-like surfaces connected on their long edges (we call them "Vents" which is where the 'V' comes from). The things I'm sorting are labels for all the long edges. The "free" edges on the outside are the single-item lists, with the name of the only surface they touch. The 2-item lists are "connecting" edge labels that contain the names of both vents they touch. And some of the internal edges are double-labeled, i.e. ['V1','V2'] and ['V2','V1']. I hope that helps.

Comment: If you cannot clarify when / how a single comes before or after a double, you are going to have a hard time implementing something...

Comment: I think your working "brute force" is reasonable, given the odd requirements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sort primarily based on length, then secondary on the item itself.  This will sort in one pass and will move the two singles to the beginning.  Then move the second single (index 1) to the end:

```py
test_list = [['V1'],['V3','V2'],['V3'],['V2','V1'],['V1','V2']]

test_list.sort(key=lambda n: (len(n), n))
test_list.append(test_list.pop(1))
print(test_list)
```

Output:

```
[['V1'], ['V1', 'V2'], ['V2', 'V1'], ['V3', 'V2'], ['V3']]
```

Comment: That's a nice clean solution, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It is a form of [natural sort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4836710/is-there-a-built-in-function-for-string-natural-sort) that is based on parsing the digits out.

You can do:

```
import re 

test_list = [['V1'],['V3','V2'],['V3'],['V2','V1'],['V1','V2']]

>>> sorted(test_list,key=lambda li: list(map(float, re.findall(r'\d+', ' '.join(li)))))

[['V1'], ['V1', 'V2'], ['V2', 'V1'], ['V3'], ['V3', 'V2']]
```

If you only have single digits, you can do:

```
sorted(test_list,key=lambda li: re.findall(r'\d+', ' '.join(li)))
```

Comment: That's the hard thing here, for me: ['V3'] has to come last...

Answer (score 0):

It is a sorting type problem with three parameters

you can do:

```
test_list = [['V1'],['V3','V2'],['V3'],['V2','V1'],['V1','V2']]
left,mid,right=0,0,len(test_list)-1
while mid<right:
    if test_list[mid][0]=='V1':
        test_list[left],test_list[mid]=test_list[mid],test_list[left]
        left+=1
        mid+=1
    elif test_list[mid][0]=='V2':
        mid+=1
    else:
        test_list[right],test_list[mid]=test_list[mid],test_list[right]
        right-=1
```

the output will be:

```
sorted_list=[['V1'], ['V1', 'V2'], ['V2', 'V1'], ['V3'], ['V3', 'V2']]
```

Comment: As above, this doesn't give me the needed result: ['V3'] has to come last...